How can I write this on latex?
How can I write:

On latex, I used \[ \] math command for the __ __ and \phantom for the spaces:

but i cant seem to get the "set of choices" directly under it in the desired fashion:

How can I do fix this?
(Note that I also want the "set of choices" to be tiny)

Do you need a line break between "set of" and "choices"?

Please show what you tried. Note, for text in math-mode you should use a \mbox{…} or \text{…} (needs amsmath). But you don't need math-mode for lines. You can use, e.g., a table or a box with \hfulefill or …

Maybe you can start from the following code that essentially uses a tabular environment with an \hline. Add the following code to your preamble:
\newcommand\fillin[2][0pt]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  \makebox[#1]{}\\\hline\raisebox{0.7ex}[0pt][0pt]{\tiny#2}%
  \end{tabular}%
}

This defines a macro \fillin[optional width]{text below line} that will insert an empty space marked by a line, with the given text below. The optional argument allows you to make the field wider than the text.

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\fillin[2][0pt]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  \makebox[#1]{}\\\hline\raisebox{0.7ex}[0pt][0pt]{\tiny#2}%
  \end{tabular}%
}
\begin{document}
Some text
\fillin{Set of Choices: Shirts}
more text
\fillin{Set of Choices: Pants}
and finally:

\fillin[5cm]{Signature}
\end{document}


It's not at all clear in the question, but my guess is that the "Set of Choices" should be on the baseline, not below.

@Teepeemm Yes, may be. Not hard to adjust, but I'll wait for the feedback of the OP ...
