Simple Question
How to write the image below in latex?:


Do you repeat your question, without adding more information about what you tried? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719640/better-method-of-alignment + https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719484/how-can-i-write-this-on-latex

I do not see how "overleaf", "horizontal-alignment" or "code" is relevant for this, but the question will probably be closed anyway as a duplicate anyways. Please find your original question about this, add only the relevant tags and a compilable example of what you tried.

Does this answer your question? How can I write this on latex?

Instead of reposting questions, you should edit and improve the existing. If the improvement is good enough, it than can be reopened. Asking again and again without improvement, does not really help.

And please use a meaningful title for questions.

Clairvoyance mode on:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{%
   \bgroup
   \sbox0{\small(Choice Set)}%
   \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}>{\centering}p{\wd0}@{}}\hline\usebox0\\#1\end{tabular}%
   \egroup
}

\begin{document}

\foo{Text A}
\foo{Text B}
\foo{Text C}
\foo{Text D Text D}

\end{document}


